# Parsing list of directories into nested dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, directory-structure

I have the following items in a list with the format of directories structure.

```py
[
    'fold/2021/',
    'fold/2021/11/',
    'fold/2021/11/01/',
    'fold/2021/11/01/123.gz',
    'fold/2021/11/01/345.gz',
    'fold/2021/12/',
    'fold/2021/12/02/',
    'fold/2022/'
]
```

I need this in the following nested dictionary structure:

```py
{
  "fold": {
    "2021": {
      "11": {
        "01": {
          "123.gz": None,
          "345.gz": None
        }
      },
      "12": {
        "02": {}
      }
    },
    "2022": {}
  }
}
```

I tried a lot with recursion and some other methods, but I am not getting this structure.

Here is what I tried:

```py
def get_directory_structure(path):
    global main_dict

    local_dict = {}

    a = path.rstrip('/').split('/')
    local_dict.setdefault(a[0], {})

    if len(a) > 1:
        return_dict = get_directory_structure(path[path.find('/')+1:])
        
        local_dict[a[0]] = return_dict

        if a[0] == 'fold':
            main_dict.update(**local_dict)
        
    return local_dict

main_dict = {}
for path in paths:
    get_directory_structure(main_dict, path)

print(main_dict)
```

Please help me with this. Thank you

*Note:- I don't have the folder on my PC. I just have the items in the list*

Comment: Should those actually be `"None"` or `None`? Anyway, that mixed format of `None`, `dict` and `list` might be problematic, e.g. what if a directory has both files (which would be a list) and subdirectories (which would be a dict)? Does the format _have_ to be like this? It might be better, both for creating and later using the structure, to have all dicts with `"02": {}` for empty directories and `"123.gz": None` for files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try like this, not using recursion but using `*`-unpacking to separate the items into the file (or `''`) and the path leading up to that, and using `setdefault` do "expand" deeper levels of the dict, if they do not exist yet, and finally add the file, if any.

```
res = {}
for item in lst:
    d = res
    *path, last = item.split("/")
    for p in path:
        d = d.setdefault(p, {})
    if last != "":
        d[last] = None
```

Afterwards, `res` should be your desired result:

```
{'fold': {'2021': {'11': {'01': {'123.gz': None, '345.gz': None}}, '12': {'02': {}}}, '2022': {}}}
```

Comment: That's pretty clever to have path and last separated (to have None as value, which I was struggling to figure out), I see how we can determine the file by slash at the end, +1